# How to fix rabbitmq installation?

Tags: macos

Somehow rabbitmq is installed on my Mac (OS X Mavericks) and I see the following process

```
500    86     1   0 Tue05PM ??         0:00.31 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=rabbitmq-server --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.rabbitmq-server/rabbitmq-server.wrapper start ; --stop-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.rabbitmq-server/rabbitmq-server.wrapper stop ; --restart-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.rabbitmq-server/rabbitmq-server.wrapper restart ; --pid=none
500    98     1   0 Tue05PM ??         0:00.00 /bin/sh /opt/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server
500   109    98   0 Tue05PM ??        64:58.43 /opt/local/lib/erlang/erts-6.0/bin/beam.smp -W w -K true -A30 -P 1048576 -- -root /opt/local/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /opt/local/var/lib/rabbitmq -- -pa /opt/local/lib/rabbitmq/bin/../lib/rabbitmq_server-3.1.5/sbin/../ebin -noshell -noinput -s rabbit boot -sname rabbit@localhost -boot start_sasl -kernel inet_default_connect_options [{nodelay,true}] -sasl errlog_type error -sasl sasl_error_logger false -rabbit error_logger {file,"/opt/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log"} -rabbit sasl_error_logger {file,"/opt/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log"} -rabbit enabled_plugins_file "/opt/local/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins" -rabbit plugins_dir "/opt/local/lib/rabbitmq/bin/../lib/rabbitmq_server-3.1.5/sbin/../plugins" -rabbit plugins_expand_dir "/opt/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand" -os_mon start_cpu_sup false -os_mon start_disksup false -os_mon start_memsup false -mnesia dir "/opt/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost" @STDOUT_STDERR_REDIRECTION@
```

However, diagnostics shows the following:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl status

Status of node rabbit@alsMac ...

Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@alsMac: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: [rabbit@alsMac]

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- unable to connect to epmd on alsMac: nxdomain (non-existing domain)

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmqctl14166@jhammar-lt'
- home dir: /opt/local/var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: u9T+ExBe4Ol0RIKh8VYXcw==
```

What should I do?

Comment: See this related question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24797947/8446

Answer (score 1):

I brew installed rabbitmq, and had this problem several weeks later after installing.

You may have a look at

```
/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
```

and run in terminal:

```
$ hostname
```

make sure the value of hostname equals the value of NODENAME

You can set the value of hostname by

```
sudo scutil --set HostName xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It turned out the `/etc/hosts` file on my Mac was empty. To resolve it I added the following using $ `sudo vim /etc/hosts`.

```
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```